# Pentaho-Hive Connection Working fine but not able to retrieve tables or column list

Tags: hadoop, hive, pentaho

I have a 4 node hadoop 1.2.1 cluster up and running where i have installed hive 1.0.0 for HiveQL implemetation. I tried setting up my pentaho data-integration 5.2.0.0 source as Hive2 connection by starting up Hiveserver2 service. The Pentaho data source is detecting the Hive service and connection is showing as OK. The problem start here. When I try to get the SQL select statement or try to explore the tables in the HIVE data source the following error is shown as below :

```
Unable to retrieve database information because of an error

Unable to get list of procedures from database meta-data: 

Unable to get list of rows from ResultSet : 

Error determining value metadata from SQL resultset metadata Method not supported
```

Can any one help me out solve this error?

Comment: How is your Hive data source configured? Did you put JARs in the classpath and use the Generic driver? If so that is not supported, instead you'd have to configure your active hadoop configuration and use the Hive 2 database dialect while configuring your datasource: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Configuring+Pentaho+for+your+Hadoop+Distro+and+Version

Comment: I have the setup connecting which mean I have the correct drivers in place. All I added were hive-jdbc-1.0.0-standalone.jar and hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar to get connectivity. But it didn't solve my problem of accessing the tables. I have set active hadoop configuration set hdp21, and both above jar files have been copied to them too. I can't still find the problem.